# Titanium NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to build a crossplatform (Android-ios) mobile application, using Titanium SDK. I didn't have a chance for a long time to build it for ios, I only used my Windows-android combination, to test it, and it works great on the Android system. But when i try to build it on the mac for the ios, i get this message, and the application shuts down in a second:

> The application has crashed with an uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException'.

Since i can not provide any relevant code, because the exception doesn't show what's the problem with my javascript code, and I certainly didn't write any native, ios specific code, i have no idea, what to do.

From the few posts i have found here is what i have tried:

- Restart Titanium Studio
- Clean the project
- Made sure to close any `ResultSet`, and `DB` objects when done with
  them (as suggested here:    [topic](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/53311/log-shows-app-termination-but-app-continues-to-run))
- Test the code on both 3.0.0 and 2.x.x versions

I'm looking forward to any advice, on how you solved this problem, if you had it!
Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
The problem was the following: I called `hasOwnProperty` on Titanium UI elements, and on the ios version these elements don't have this function (which is weird, since every javascript objects have it, if i'm not mistaken).

If you have similar problems, i recomend reading this [article](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/02/what-is-a-titanium-proxy-object.html), besides mr.VVoos answer, it helps a lot in avoiding the problems i had!

Comment: What I do with this type of exception is put a breakpoint at the beginning of the code (first line), then step debug through until you hit this exception. Often this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm developing with Titanim and iOS & Android for a long time. Usually there are many differences between iOS and Android parts of the code.

In most cases this exceptions means that an operation is called that is not available for the called class. (In Java this would mean: Class.method() -> Class has no method called method()).

You can try to run the app in debug mode (on iOS Simulator). There is a big advantage debuggin iOS compared to Android. Usually the iOS simulator stops if there is an exception and it shows the JavaScript code that caused the exception. Unfortunately this doesn't work all the time and it only works on simulator.

If this does not provide any further information you can do the following:
 - go to your app.js and set a breakpoint in one of the first lines.
 - start app in debug mode.
 - move on this breakpoint each time until your app crashes - maybe then you are able to detect the error or provide further information.

One last tip: Check your code if there are any platform-specific parts. (Like Android Intents and something that is not available on iOS).

I know that this can be very ugly but we had to solve many of these nasty issues while migrating from iOS to Android.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i will definitely try to test if everything has it's methods. Then the line by line testing. If i give custom functions to Titanium proxy objects, like windows or buttons, it should work fine on all platforms right?

Comment: Well, usually you can apply custom properties to **all** objects (sometimes there are errors because of special keywords - i think we had a similar problem because there was a wrong leyword and we had the same error like you). But it's better to create objects containing the ui element and additional information (see best practices of titanium). Functions applied to UI objects or transported via eventlisteners are not working properly. @bali182

Comment: Thanks for the help, i found the problem... I called hasOwnProperty on Titanium Ui elements :D